# how to put my box in every row of my looping

Tags: fpdf

I want to put multiple box in every 1st and last column per row in my array of looping. Also the result of my looping is twice as it is

```
$w = array(82,95); //for XY dimension   
for($i=0; $i < 2; $i++) {

    $pdf->Row(array(utf8_decode($pdf->Rect($w[$i], 10, 7, 3, 'D')),
    utf8_decode($client_code),
    utf8_decode($full_name),
    utf8_decode($prod_name),
    number_format($loan_amount,2),
    number_format($total_outstanding_principal + $int_bal,2),
    date_format(date_create($start_date),"d F Y"),
    $num_paid,
    $num_unpaid,
    $total_installment,
    number_format($repayment - $total_penalty,2),
    date_format(date_create($end_date),"d F Y"),
    date_format(date_create($last_paid_date),"d F Y"),
    number_format($repayment,2),
    number_format($overdue,2),""));
}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the rest of our code as well as a sample of the data that we can test with. As it stands right now your question isn't really clear. Also, there is no `Row` method in `fPDF` so please include that definition.